# how to use scipy.special.expi (Exponential integral) in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, exponential, integral

I have to code scipy.special.expi in tensorflow but I don't know how!!!!
please, someone, help
since there is no as such direct code in tensorflow so I'm stuck here
please help!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not easy to implement that in TensorFlow since it is not given out of the box and the implementation is not trivial. The SciPy version is implemented in Fortran, see [`scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f#L5231-L5266).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know much about this function, but based on the Fortran implementation in SciPy, the function `EIX` in [`scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f#L5231-L5266), I have put together a TensorFlow implementation following each step there. It is only for positive values, though, as the computation for negative values included a loop harder to vectorize.

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf

def expi(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    # When X is zero
    m_0 = tf.equal(x, 0)
    y_0 = -math.inf + tf.zeros_like(x)
    # When X is negative
    m_neg = x < 0
    # This should be -e1xb(-x) according to ScyPy
    # (negative exponential integral -1)
    # Here it is just left as NaN
    y_neg = math.nan + tf.zeros_like(x)
    # When X is less or equal to 40 - Power series around x = 0
    m_le40 = x <= 40
    k = tf.range(1, 101, dtype=x.dtype)
    r = tf.cumprod(tf.expand_dims(x, -1) * k / tf.square(k + 1), axis=-1)
    ga = tf.constant(0.5772156649015328, dtype=x.dtype)
    y_le40 = ga + tf.log(x) + x * (1 + tf.reduce_sum(r, axis=-1))
    # Otherwise (X is greater than 40) - Asymptotic expansion (the series is not convergent)
    k = tf.range(1, 21, dtype=x.dtype)
    r = tf.cumprod(k / tf.expand_dims(x, -1), axis=-1)
    y_gt40 = tf.exp(x) / x * (1 + tf.reduce_sum(r, axis=-1))
    # Select values
    return tf.where(
        m_0, y_0, tf.where(
        m_neg, y_neg, tf.where(
        m_le40, y_le40, y_gt40)))
```

A small test

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.special
import numpy as np

# Test
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 20)
y = scipy.special.expi(x)
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    y_tf = sess.run(expi(x))
print(np.allclose(y, y_tf))
# True
```

Note however this will take more memory than SciPy, because it is unrolling the approximation loops in memory instead of computing one step at a time.

Comment: thank you so much, but i can't i just input a single number rather than a list? when i'm trying to input just a single number  say 5, it's giving me an error

Comment: @QuamerNasim Right, I added `x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)` at the beginning to make sure `x` it is a tensor. Should work for that case now (you must use float values, not integers).